# Serving static files on Google AppEngine with a prefixed url

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, gunicorn, static-files

I have an existing GAE service (default) and I am adding a new service (admin). This is using python3.8, gunicorn and flask.

I have a dispatch.yaml file which redirects requests with `/admin` to the new service. And I write the `app.yaml` in the new service to only respond to urls with this prefix.

The directory structure is a bit messy, but it is as follows:

```
<root>
| app.yaml
| dispatch.yaml
| main.py
| static
| | css
| | | x.css
| | | y.css
| admin
| | admin_service.yaml
| | main.py
| | static
| | | main.css
```

The `admin_service.yaml` looks like this:

```
runtime: python38
service: admin

handlers:
- url: admin/static
  static_dir: static

- url: /admin/.*
  script: auto
```

The problem is: when I run the admin_service, either locally or on GAE, it cannot find my static resources. Requests for `<server>/admin/static/main.css` return 404, but `<server>/static/main.css` return my files. This does not help, though, because all requests for this service must be under the `/admin/` prefix.

I tried many variations, including using `static_files`, with the same issue.

I expected that `/admin/static` would be interpreted as a prefix and that everything after this would be appended to `static_dir` to generate a resource path.

Instead, only the actual directory name matters.

Answer (score 0):

You have a file `<server>/admin/static/main.css` and you want anything that starts with `/admin/static` to be handled by the static path handler you've defined. Your url path should thus be `/admin/static` and your directory should be `static/`

```
- url: /admin/static
  static_dir: static/
```

In addition, you should ensure that if you're using relative urls on your admin pages for the static files, they end up with a full url of `<server>/admin/static/main.css` and not `<server>/static/main.css` cos the latter is for your default service.